# What can a sequence of functions which are integrable and the integration are bounded imply?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Now we have a seq. of integral function {$f_k$} on a measurable set $E$ (not necessarily bounded) and a positive real number $M$ s.t. $\int_E |f_k| d\lambda < M$ holds for all k and $f_k$ converges to some $f$ almost everywhere.

How to show that
$$\int_E (|f_k|-|f_k - f|)d\lambda = \int_E|f|d\lambda$$
as k $\to$ $∞$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fatou's Lemma $\int |f| \leq \lim \inf \int |f_k| <\infty$.

By Fatou's Lemma again $\int 2 |f| \leq \lim \inf \int [|f|+|f_k|-|f-f_k|]$ [Note that $|f|+|f_k|-|f-f_k|] \geq 0$ and $|f|+|f_k|-|f-f_k|] \to 2|f|$ a.e.].

Subtracting $\int |f|$ from both sides we get  $\int  |f| \leq \lim \inf \int [|f_k|-|f-f_k|]\leq \lim \sup \int [|f_k|-|f-f_k|]\leq \int |f|$ since $|f_k|-|f-f_k|\leq  |f|$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: It seems that I can even do it by DCT since $|f_k| - |f_k - f|$ is dominated by $|f|$. In this view, it is quite trivia.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot :D